# Dockerfile: Python3 not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to convert a bash script to a Dockerfile since we are going the containerization route with AWS Batch

Basically I install CPLEX (an optimization library) and Anaconda, install some related packages, check if my environment it good to go, and then kick off a shell script to run the batch job.

Here is a snippet of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

# Download packages for container
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum -y install which unzip aws-cli \
RUN yum install -y tar.x86_64 
RUN yum install gzip -y
RUN yum install ncompress -y
RUN yum -y install wget
RUN yum install -y nano

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /setup

#: Copy CPLEX installer binary and installation script.
COPY cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin /setup/
COPY cplex_installer_input.sh /setup/

#: Install CPLEX and update .bashrc
RUN chmod +x /setup/cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin 
RUN chmod +x cplex_installer_input.sh
RUN ./cplex_installer_input.sh | bash cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin 
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux' >>/root/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux

#: Download Anaconda
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/
RUN bash Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin' >>/root/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin

RUN conda install pandas -y \
    && conda install numpy -y \
    && conda install ujson -y \
    && pip install docplex \
    && pip install boto3 \
    && pip install grpcio \
    && pip install grpcio-tools



RUN python3 -m docplex.mp.environment

ADD fetch_and_run.sh /usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh"]
```

From there, I kick off a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
date
echo "Args: $@"
env
echo "script_path: $1"
echo "script_name: $2"
echo "path_prefix: $3"
echo "jobID: $AWS_BATCH_JOB_ID"
echo "jobQueue: $AWS_BATCH_JQ_NAME"
echo "computeEnvironment: $AWS_BATCH_CE_NAME"

echo "current directory: $(pwd)"

mkdir /tmp/scripts/
aws s3 cp $1 /tmp/scripts/$2
python3 /tmp/scripts/${@:2}
```

But for some reason, I keep getting

```
/tmp/tmp.hQlWYBEFs/batch-file-temp: line 20: python3: command not found
```

Do I need to change some PATH variables? Why isn't Docker picking up my Python 3 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image needs to have python3 installed. Building images works off of files and programs that exist *in the container*. The python3 you have installed on your own system is not available.